returning a research laptop
About a year ago, my PhD advisor asked me to find a laptop for my research project and send him the link so he could purchase it. I provided the link, and now, almost a year later, he contacted me to pick up the laptop from his office. However, when I received it, I noticed it was an open-box laptop that he had originally bought for someone else in his research group, but that person didn’t like it. He essentially passed it on to me. I feel a significant amount of discrimination, as all the other students were allowed to pick their own laptops themselves. I would like to return this laptop, as it’s not the one I selected. How should I go about returning it, since I don’t want it?
I told the professor that I don't want the laptop since it’s not the one I had originally selected, but he said I have to keep it for now and that he will buy a different one when extra funds become available. I still don’t want to keep this laptop.

Did you tell him what you just told us? Is it normal that getting a laptop takes a year, and if not did you contact them while waiting?

of course I told him, he siad I have to keep it. But I dont want to keep this

Well, then don't keep it but don't expect another one. Limited budgets mean choices have to be made on various things.

What sort of discrimination do you believe is going on? That’s a potentially serious charge.

This basically comes down to:
Who is paying for the laptop?
There're only two answers: either you are paying for it, or your professor is (presumably out of his research grant).

If you are paying for it: you don't need his approval. Buy your laptop and return this laptop, telling the professor that you no longer need it because you have bought your own.
If he is paying for it: you have no grounds for complaint. He is lending you the laptop, and you're getting to use it for free, free being the keyword. Since it costs you nothing, you should have no expectations.

In the latter scenario you could still return it, of course, if you have some other arrangement for doing your research (e.g. borrowing your friend's laptop).

I am not paying directly it comes out of our research fund. So I am not sure why you refer to those two scenarios.

@programmer_smart unless you applied for, are listed as the Principal Investigator, and won the grant, your professor is paying for the laptop. That would make it the second bullet point above.

but I consider it rude to push someone to accept a faulty laptop that some other teammate has bought in the group and they did not like the laptop and now pushing me to use that laptop just because they did not like it.

This isn't a difficult question. Someone is offering something they paid for that you can use for free. You can take it, or you can leave it. But you shouldn't expect them to pay for a different thing just because you want the different thing. If you want something different, someone will have to pay for it, and the way I see it is that the person who pays for it gets to choose what you get.
The fact that you previously made a suggestion on what it is you would like does not make a difference in all of this. There's a limited amount of resources, and if you get something for free, you can't be choosy.

the professor is trying to push me to accept a faulty laptop that some other teammate had bought in the group and she did not like the laptop. Now he is trying to push me to use that laptop just because they did not like it. I consider this unetical behaviour of professor. I wont use it and want to return as soon as possible

You're certainly welcome to do that. You might just have to use your own personal laptop in that case.

You do, however, recognize that in all of this, you come over like a petulant and spoiled child. Or perhaps you don't -- in which case I think it's worthwhile pointing out what I imagine everyone here is thinking.
